# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') when function is passed as an onPress prop

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to pass a function onPress prop to my custom component which should navigate to the next screen.
This is the function

```
const clickedItem = (data) => {
        navigation.navigate('articledetail', { data: data })
    }
```

This is my component and I am passing props like this

```
  <CardCus
                    title={item.title}
                    user={item.author_name}
                    itemimage={item.image}
                    onPressed={() => clickedItem(item)}
                />
```

and using the onpressed in my component. `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onPressed}` like this
It works fine on main screen if it is called but it gives the error **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')** if passed as a prop. How can I handle this?

Comment: provide more detailed code

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, I think you should use hook like

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
------

const navigation = useNavigation();
------
```

Comment: I have edited the question please take a look now

Answer (score 0):

You should use props prototype and also execute the function which comes to props.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => props.onPressed()}>
...
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```